# How to spread an array without using a spread operator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there a way through functions or array methods to spread an array without the spread operator.
I was solving Algo challenges on FCC and was just curious about this.

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  var newArr = [];
  args.forEach(arr => newArr.push(...arr));
  return newArr.reduce((array, num) => {
    if(!array.includes(num)) {
      array.push(num);
    }
    return array;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: You're too curious. / Why do you want to not using them? / What about `eval`? Unobservable behavior.

Comment: please add some data to test the function. what do you expect?

Comment: If you didn't use spread syntax, it wouldn't be called *spreading* any more… what do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
var newArr = [];
args.forEach(arr => newArr.push(...arr));
```

this part of your code is just flattening the arguments by one level, and can also be written as

```
var newArr  = [].concat.apply([], arguments);
```

and

```
return newArr.reduce((array, num) => {
   if(!array.includes(num)) {
     array.push(num);
   }
   return array;
}, []);
```

is returning a version of that without duplicates. Wich can also be achieved differently

```
//adding that, because it's so much simpler than your reduce
return [...new Set(newArr)]; 
return Array.from(new Set(newArr)); 

//or
return newArr.filter(function(v,i){ return newArr.indexOf(v) === i });
```

and the whole thing

```js
function uniteUnique( /*...arrays*/ ) {
  return [].concat.apply([], arguments)
    .filter(function(v, i, a) {
      return a.indexOf(v) === i
    });
}

console.log(uniteUnique(
  1, 
  [2, 3, 4], 
  2, 
  [3, 5], 
  [2, 4, 6, 8], 
  8, 
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

---

If you want to flatten by multiple (all) levels, you can do this like

```
//reusable helper
function _flatten(into, value){
  if(Array.isArray(value)) 
    return value.reduce(_flatten, into);

  into.push(value);
  return into;
}

function _unique(v,i,a){ 
  return a.indexOf(v) === i;
}

function uniteUnique( /*...arrays*/ ) {
  return _flatten([], [].slice.call(arguments))
    .filter(_unique);
}
```

or the all-in-one solution

```
function uniteUnique( /*...arrays*/ ) {
  return (function _recursive(into, value){
    if(Array.isArray(value)) 
      return value.reduce(_recursive, into);

    if(into.indexOf(value) === -1) into.push(value);
    return into;
  })([], [].slice.call(arguments));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArray = [...oldArray];
```

will produce identical output as using [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
const newArray = [].concat(oldArray)
```

if you want to merge all arrays into one then you can do it with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const newArray = args.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr), [])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).  Consider this article about emulating spread with `apply()`: [Using 'apply' to Emulate JavaScript's Upcoming Spread Operator](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/using-apply-to-emulate-javascripts-upcoming-spread-operator.html).

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  var newArr = [];

  args.forEach(arr => Array.prototype.push.apply(newArr, arr));

  return newArr.reduce((array, num) => {
    if(!array.includes(num)) {
      array.push(num);
    }
    return array;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: @user202729 I mixed up `apply` and `call` at the very start of my answer.

Comment: "question"? "answer"?

Comment: @user202729 Yes, I also mixed up "answer" with "question" at the start of my comment.  My morning is not starting well.